# how to set drupal 7 file upload path?

Tags: file-upload, drupal-7

I saw drupal 7 file upload path is default to "public//" but, I want to change it to my ubuntu machine specific path e.g. "/tmp/upload" . I have my customized drupal7 installed so, currently I could not find the uploaded file. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it admin/config/media/file-system